# what is the cause of error: Unable to check TDB lock owner as the lock file contains invalid data

Tags: jena

When I start the fuseki server with the a bash file containing

```
    cd /home/frank/additionalSpace/AF_amd_install/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0
exec /home/frank/additionalSpace/AF_amd_install/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0/fuseki-server -v --update --loc=/home/frank/april19test /testDB
```

i get consistently the error

```
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Server     INFO  Running in read-only mode for /testDB
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Server     INFO  Fuseki 2.5.0
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/home/frank/additionalSpace/AF_amd_install/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/home/frank/additionalSpace/AF_amd_install/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0/run
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Servlet    INFO  Initializing Shiro environment
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///home/frank/additionalSpace/AF_amd_install/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0/run/shiro.ini
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Config     INFO  Template file: templates/config-tdb-dir
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Config     INFO  TDB dataset: directory=/home/frank/april19test
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: Unable to check TDB lock owner as the lock file contains invalid data
[2017-04-20 21:43:23] WebAppContext WARN  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@19f9d595{/,file:///home/frank/additionalSpace/AF_amd_install/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0/webapp/,STARTING}
org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.FileException: Unable to check TDB lock owner as the lock file contains invalid data
```

I am surprised that it opens the db in read-only mode when I ask for `--update`. The directory april19 test is freshly created.

when i change the code to

```
exec /home/frank/jena/apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0/fuseki-server -v --update --mem /marchDB
```

it opens without problem. In the web interface i can also start a permanent db. I do not have the above problem on other computers.

what am I doing wrong? 
what must I do to correct the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "contains invalid data" -- try stopping the server, deleting the lock file and restarting.  Also check no other instance of the server is running and file permissions.

Comment: did not work - i restarted (after killing any previous servers). i saw an additional line in the error message, which could be meaningful: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""``

Answer (score 0):

What helped in the end was to re-install jena and fuseki from the zip files (which takes only a few seconds). I had the zip files in the same directory where the expanded directories where. Deleted the expanded ones and re-extracted the files in the same location they were before. The error is gone.
I assume i had some "dirt" in these files.